# How to make the ion-item responsive

Tags: html, css, ionic-framework, ionic2, ionic3

**.html**

```
<ion-content>
   <ion-item>
     <div>User Name</div>
     <ion-icon item-right name="arrow-forward"></ion-icon>
     <div>You can have a unique username</div>
   </ion-item>
</ion-content>
```

From the above piece of code I have the structure lie below:

[image]

When I decrease the width of the screen it looks as follows

[image]

Clipping the content and not having fixed gap between the content and the arrow which is very unresponsive.
How can I make it responsive?

Comment: did you try `text-wrap`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like **Suraj** pointed try adding text-wrap

```
 <ion-item>
    <div text-wrap>
       <p>User Name</p>
       <p>You can have a unique username</p>
    </div>
    <ion-icon item-right name="arrow-forward"></ion-icon>
</ion-item>
```